# Fail a test with Chai.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

In JUnit you can fail a test by doing:

```
fail("Exception not thrown");
```

What's the best way to achieve the same using Chai.js?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are many ways to fake a failure – like the `assert.fail()` mentioned by @DmytroShevchenko –, but usually, it is possible to avoid these crutches and express the intent of the test in a better way, which will lead to more meaningful messages if the tests fail.

For instance, if you expect a exception to be thrown, why not say so directly:

```
expect( function () {
    // do stuff here which you expect to throw an exception
} ).to.throw( Error );
```

As you can see, when testing exceptions, you have to wrap your code in an anonymous function.

Of course, you can refine the test by checking for a more specific error type, expected error message etc. See `.throw` in the [Chai docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for more.

Comment: I completely agree that what you have outlined is a better approach.

Answer (score 66):

There's [**`assert.fail()`**](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/). You can use it like this:

```
assert.fail(0, 1, 'Exception not thrown');
```

Comment: ... and your answer is the right one in case there is no other option, so you get my upvote, too :)

Comment: @hashchange There's one good example where you would use that instead of "to.throw" and that's in the case of where you might throw errors in object constructors.

Answer (score 17):

Just try

```
expect.fail("custom error message");
```

or

```
should.fail("custom error message");
```

as decribed in chai docs : https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_fail

Answer (score 4):

I also stumbled that here was no direct `fail(msg)`.
For some time, I worked around with...

```
assert.isOk(false, 'timeOut must throw')
```

(Using this in places that should not be reachable, i.e. in promise-testing…)

Chai is compatible with standard ES6 errors, so this works:

```
throw new Error('timeOut must throw')
```

…or, since [assert itself is essentially the same as assert.isOK](http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#assertexpression-message)… my favourite is:

```
assert(false,'timeOut must throw')
```

…well, almost as short as `assert.fail(…`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this way

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const exists = true;
expect(!exists).to.throw('Unknown request type');
```